# Python Calling Current Directrory

Tags: python, fast-ai

I am using fasitai library and when ı tried the loading model ı want to take model from current directory.

```
learn = load_learner('This arg. have to my current directory','model.pkl')
```

I tried os.get_cwd() and ' ./ ' but they aren't worked. Thanks

Comment: How about `os.path.abspath('.')`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
learn = load_learner('','model.pkl')
```

the first arg. had to be space '' .

Comment: `''` is not a space.